# LIs and FieldSet spacing issue with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

We have an issue with fieldsets inside of LIs in IE11.

Example:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <fieldset>Lorem Ipsum</fieldset>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1yhLemx9/

In IE11, You'll notice that the fieldset ends up appearing a line below the LI bullet/number, It's as if the fieldset had top-padding of 1rem or so.

But it doesn't. No amount of setting paddings and margins to zero, or adjusting position or the like seems to get rid of the mysterious space above it.

I'd assume this is a known issue of some sort, but the issues I'm finding are of people trying to add space to a fieldset in IE rather than remove mysterious space from it.

Has anyone ran into this? Found a fix?

Comment: Floating the fieldset to the left seems to kinda fix the issue (http://jsfiddle.net/1yhLemx9/1/), only then you get a bit of a width problem - width:100% makes the fieldset stretch over the whole width in IE, but then in Chrome that makes it too wide, so that it slides below the number there now.